# Change applicationbar buttonicon at runtime

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a WP7 app and the application needs to change the icon of a button on the application bar given the state of a request.
I have tried:

```
if (App.Servers[index].ServerState == "Enabled")
{
  DetailsAppBar.btnStart.IconUri = new Uri("/AppBar/appbar.stop.rest.png");
}

else
{
  DetailsAppBar.btnStart.IconUri = new Uri("/AppBar/appbar.transport.play.rest.png");
}
```

This doesn't give me an error in the code, but it can't compile.... 
any hints to do this is appreciated :)

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ApplicationBar is a special control that does not behave as other Silverlight controls (see [Peter Torr's post on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements.aspx)). One of the consequences is that names given in XAML to app bar buttons generate fields in code-behind that are always null.

I'm guessing that in your case the btnStart field in DetailsAppBar is set to null, and thus trying to set its IconUri property results in a NullReferenceException being thrown.

To access a button in an application bar, you must instead reference it by its zero-based index in the buttons list. For instance, the code below returns a reference to the third button in the app bar:

```
button = (IApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2];
```

Answer (score 8):

figured it out...

```
((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2]).IconUri = new Uri("/AppBar/appbar.stop.rest.png",UriKind.Relative);
```

did the trick :)