# AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 50 Position: 45]

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

This is my code of ApplicationBar (The code which is causing error due to databinding)

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" >
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/icons/prevItem.png" x:Name="prevItem"
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsPrevTopicButtonEnabled}"
                                            Text="Prev item" Click="prevItem_Click">

            </shell:ApplicationBarIconButton>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/icons/nextItem.png" 
                                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsNextTopicButtonEnabled}"
                                            Text="Next item" x:Name="nextItem" Click="nextItem_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="mnuPrevItem" Text="{Binding Path=PreviousTopic.Title}"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem x:Name="mnuNextItem" Text="{Binding Path=NextTopic.Title}"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

These are my properties in code-behind :-

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviousTopicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PreviousTopic",
    typeof(Topic), typeof(ArticleViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public Topic PreviousTopic
{
    get { return GetValue(PreviousTopicProperty) as Topic; }
    set
    {

        SetValue(PreviousTopicProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty NextTopicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("NextTopic",
    typeof(Topic), typeof(ArticleViewer), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public Topic NextTopic
{
    get { return GetValue(NextTopicProperty) as Topic; }
    set
    {

        SetValue(NextTopicProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsNextTopicButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsNextTopicButtonEnabled",
    typeof(bool), typeof(ArticleViewer), new PropertyMetadata(true));
public bool IsNextTopicButtonEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsNextTopicButtonEnabledProperty); }
    set
    {

        SetValue(IsNextTopicButtonEnabledProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPrevTopicButtonEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsPrevTopicButtonEnabled",
typeof(bool), typeof(ArticleViewer), new PropertyMetadata(true));
public bool IsPrevTopicButtonEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPrevTopicButtonEnabledProperty); }
    set
    {

        SetValue(IsPrevTopicButtonEnabledProperty, value);
    }
}
```

In the construtor I have this line:-

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

The binding is not working properly but I have no idea Why! I know INotifyPropertyChanged doesn't quiet work well with WP7 as Silverlight 4.0. But I already have DependencyProperties. What more can I do for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationBar is a bit odd as a control... see this post ["Why application bar is not a FrameworkElement?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements.aspx)

I think because the ApplicationBar is not a FrameworkElement you can't data bind within it - similar to Derek's answer to [Getting AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE while data binding in WP7 User control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352401/getting-ag-e-parser-bad-property-value-while-data-binding-in-wp7-user-control)

I'm sorry to say that you may just have to adjust the ApplicationBar in CodeBehind rather than through databinding - see [Change applicationbar buttonicon at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718924/change-applicationbar-buttonicon-at-runtime)

Comment: - How can I adjust it in code? When I access this stupid control (prevItem) in my Loaded event of MainPage.xaml.cs I get Null. Can you explain how can it be Null in loaded event?

Comment: See the answers in the question I linked - you cannot use names - you have always need to use array index access like `(IApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[2]` - might not be as nice as databinding but you just have to grin and bear it.